# How to load the DataBase and their table names in C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to load the database names and their table names in Windows Forms.

I use this code to Get the server names in the System

```
private void ServerName()
       {
           try
           {

               DataTable dt = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(true);
               if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
               {
                   foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                   {
                       string serverName = dr[0].ToString();
                       if (!serverName.Contains("\\SQLEXPRESS"))
                       {
                           serverName = serverName + "\\SQLEXPRESS";
                       }
                       comboBox1.Items.Add(serverName);
                   }
                   comboBox1.Items.Add(@".\sqlexpress");
               }
           }
           catch (Exception)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Problem In Fetching Server Information.");
           }

       }
```

I use to load the Database Names of that particular Server.

```
enter code here

private void DBnames()
        {
            server = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            database = "master";
            con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=" + database + ";Integrated Security=True;");
            con.Open();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name FROM sys.databases", con);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0]);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

Now i want load the table names for this Data base

I use this code

```
private void TBnames()
        {
            con.Open();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'",con);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                comboBox3.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0]);
            }



            con.Close();

        }
```

But it is not working. Please help me to get the tables of the selected DB.

Thanks in advance..

Now i got the answer..

Just change the  code in TBnames:

```
private void TBnames()
            {
                con.Open();
                string s = comboBox2.Text;
               // MessageBox.Show(s);
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Use " + s, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM sys.tables", con);
                ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                //dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    comboBox3.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0]);
                }
                con.Close();
            }
```

It's working..

Comment: What isn't working? Are you obtaining an error message? An Exception? Are you not getting back the results you expect (if at all)?

Comment: It shows the database designs. Now i change the code and it's working..

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ maybe :)

```
using (var db = new DataClassesDataContext(getConnectionString))
{
    db.Mapping.GetTables();
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655883(v=vs.90).aspx